# Sprites disappear from scene when change the size of screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am coding my first game by using `sprite kit`.

I added boundary around my `scene` but when I have different screens for different devices, it shows that there is some gap region and the `sprites` will be disappear from the screen when they reach that gap region. I would like to know how to set the boundary automatically to be exactly the screen size when changing the screen size?

Comment: You should update your question with relevant code from view controller and also from GameScene (part where you create boundary). Without actual code nobody can do more than a guessing...And I guess the issue is probably related with how you initialize a scene in view controller, or how you create a boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

This will take your current game scene, `scene` and set the boundaries of it to that of the screen.
Hope that helps :D